# how to get a specific data value from a body?

Tags: node.js, api, get

I'm using the "request" npm to send POST , PUT , Get and Delete requests to my API.

how can I get the value of a specific data in the body ?

example : I want to get the value of _id and store it

```
  body: '{"_id":"58332517c4afbd230074732e","PushToken":"1","AuthCode":"1","DeviceID":"1"}'
```

my current get request is

```
request.get('http://localhost:3000/api/pass/58332517c4afbd230074732e', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log( body._id);
        console.log( response.body._id);
    }
});
```

I tried both, `body._id` and `response.body._id` they both return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returned body is a JSON string, which you need to parse it into an object first.

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(data._id);
```